# How to execute method on listbox item select asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Need to select an item from listbox and on select a method is executed load_data() , the data is loaded and displayed but instead after that the page gets refreshed and again the value displayed is set to default . Its autopostback property is true . What should I do ?

```
 protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        load_data(listBox1.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. How it is getting refreshed? When you are binding data into your listbox etc.

Comment: Are you binding the list box on post back i.e. when `load-data()` method is called?

Comment: it is only called at listbox_selectedindexchanged() and no the data is not binded at page_load

Comment: If you are binding it then the `selected value will always be lost`. But if you are not binding it on post back, then the selected value will be retained if view state is enabled for your drop down.

Comment: but `load_data()` is called when  drop down index is changed?  It doesn't matter if it's called after page load or not. if yes, then the selected value will not be retained. Can you post the code for `load_data()`?

Comment: load_data() method is too long , posting algorithm -> get value of listbox -> search data with value in databse -> get data -> post to chart -> update chart-> display

Comment: are you setting the data source of listbox in this `load_data()` method?

Comment: no the data source is not set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101245/discussion-between-phpnet-and-sunil).

Answer (score 0):

If you are initially databinding your ListBox in your `Page_Load` method, make sure you only databind when it's not a postback like this...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // initial databind ListBox here (where the default data is loaded)
    }
}
```

You can still keep your SelectedIndexChanged event

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    load_data(listBox1.SelectedItem.Text);
}
```